# Sharepoint Filter List Items

Tags: c#, powershell, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, .net-5

I have a list in sharepoint, and what i want to do is want to fetch the data using c#. I want it to return the value from sharepoint based on a condition.

This is what have so far,

```
        public async Task<int> FetchSharePointListItem(string siteId, string libraryName, Dictionary<string, string> matchCriteria)
        {
            try
            {
                var list = await Client.Sites[siteId].Lists.Request().Filter($"displayName eq '{libraryName}'").GetAsync();
                // Extract the library ID from the response
                string listId = list[0].Id;

                List<Option> options = new List<Option>
                {
                   //Creating header
                   new HeaderOption("Prefer","HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly")
                };

                var filter = string.Join(" and ", matchCriteria.Select(kv => $"{kv.Key} eq '{kv.Value}'"));
                var items = await Client.Sites[siteId].Lists[listId].Items.Request(options).Filter(filter).GetAsync();
                return items.Count;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
```

However when executing this i get the error

```
Exception: Code: BadRequest
Message: Invalid filter clause
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2023-05-19T15:54:32
    request-id: 650048ff-9e76-4798-96ec-e3f4d50c7b1f
    client-request-id: 650048ff-9e76-4798-96ec-e3f4d50c7b1f
ClientRequestId: 650048ff-9e76-4798-96ec-e3f4d50c7b1f
```

In powershell this works

```
    $filterExpressions = foreach ($entry in $MatchCriteria.GetEnumerator()) {
        $columnName = $entry.Key
        $columnValue = $entry.Value
        "$columnName eq '$columnValue'"
    }
    
    $selectFields = "Title,Username,OrgID,Firstname,MiddleName,LastName,Email"
    $filterQuery = $filterExpressions -join " and "
    
    $apiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$SiteId/lists/$ListId/items?expand=fields(select=$selectFields)&=fields/$filterExpressions"
```

I am running on a console using visual studio 2019. using .Net 5.0
Any help would be appreciated.

this is what my filter look right now

```
title eq '4398439'
```

Comment: Play with this part (`var filter = string.Join(" and ", matchCriteria.Select(kv => $"{kv.Key} eq '{kv.Value}'"));`) having it echo to the terminal to ensure the string result is as expected blank spaces and all. It seem to not like the filter clause and says it is invalid so just break it down and echo the `list` after setting it and then echo `listId` and then on to the next for full output. I suspect something is not being built properly there and it's just a trivial matter. Ensure all those parts are working including `string listId = list[0].Id;` too. Compare PS and .Net outputs too.

Comment: I also try to put it has a string in the filter same thing but I will try space. Anyway in c# to see what the graph url is before being send?